# Command line options with argument in shell script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, getopts

I have a script to get ldap user name, email and mobile number:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter Unix id > "
read UNIXID
ldapsearch -x "(cn=$UNIXID)" | awk '/givenName/||/mobile/||/mail/'
```

Here is the output of the script:

```
#./lsearch
Enter Unix id > in15004
givenName: Mr. Xyz
mail: x@abc.com
mobile: 9xxxxxxxx1
```

Now I want to modify the script so that I can run it in non-interactive mode, e.g:

```
#./lsearch –i in15004 # (i meand ID)
givenName: Mr. Xyz
mail: x@abc.com
mobile: 9xxxxxxxx1
```

or:

```
#./lsearch –n Xyz* # (n means givenName)
givenName: Mr. Xyz
mail: x@abc.com
mobile: 9xxxxxxxx1
```

or:

```
./lsearch –e x@*.com # (e means email id)
givenName: Mr. Xyz
mail: x@abc.com
mobile: 9xxxxxxxx1
```

How can I do that? I tried below :

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts "i:" OPTION; do
    case $OPTION in
    i)
        UNIXID=$OPTARG
        ;;
    esac
done
ldapsearch -x "(cn=$UNIXID)" | awk '/givenName/||/mobile/||/mail/'
#ldapsearch -x "(mail=$MAIL)" | awk '/givenName/||/mobile/||/mail/
#ldapsearch -x "(givenName=$NAME)" | awk '/givenName/||/mobile/||/mail/
exit 0;
```

Here is the output of the script:

```
#./lsearch -i in15004
givenName: Mr. Xyz
mail: x@abc.com
mobile: 9xxxxxxxx1
```

I think similar like above will do. But not sure how to make the loop.

Comment: what did you already try doing?

Comment: If you suffix your `ldapsearch` command with the field names that you want, it will return `dn` plus only those selected fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use getopts (noted the "s") to get the command line arguments you can do something like

```
while getopts "i:n:e:" OPT; do
    case "$OPT" in
        i)
            # do stuff with the i option
            ID="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        n)
            # do stuff with the n option
            ;;
        e)
            # do stuff with the e option
            ;;
    esac
done
```

The getopts takes 2 arguments, a string saying what options it should look for and the name of the variable to store the current option it found in.  The string to tell it what options to look for is the letter for the short option, and if that later is followed by a colon it means the option takes an argument, it isn't just a flag that is set.

Comment: FWIW, when using `getopts` its easy to support a `-h` option to print a help message for the user.

Comment: @Eric.Renouf Got it, but how to do the looping? #./lsearch -i in15004 is working but #./lsearch -n Mr. Xyz or #./lsearch -m x@abc.com is not working.

Comment: @SM_IND I'm not sure what loop it is that you're talking about trying to include there.  Looking at the sample code you posted, you are only processing one flag, `-i`.  If you want to handle the others you'll need to add those to the string you pass to getopts and then add a case for each flag.  You can have the case actually call your `lsearch` without just setting variables if that helps too

Answer (score 0):

This is quite basic. You can pass the name as an argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

UNIXID=$1

ldapsearch -x "(cn=$UNIXID)" | awk '/givenName/||/mobile/||/mail/'

#####################


#./lsearch in15004

givenName: Mr. Xyz

mail: x@abc.com

mobile: 9xxxxxxxx1
```